# Change UITextView with Floating Number Variable

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to display an UITextView on centre, dynamically both for 3.5 inch display and 4 inch display. but it has top and bottom 'padding' 20 pts.

So I create this code to measure UIView's height:

```
CGFloat screenHeight = _screen.frame.size.height;
float scrollHeight = screenHeight - 40;
```

then I add this line to set the screen :

```
_screen.frame = CGRectMake(20, 40, 320, scrollHeight);
```

but I see no difference on my 4 inch iPod touch... what did I do wrong?

UPDATE : 
here's my .h file :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *screen;
```

and here's my .m file :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    _screen.frame = CGRectMake(20, 40, 320, screenHeight);
}
```

Comment: try translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO on the textView's superview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the screen informations for sure like this:

```
screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
CGRect statusBarFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
```

You can calculate with these dynamically every height or width you want, and your views will got the right frame.

EDIT:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    _screen.frame = CGRectMake(20, 40, 320, screenHeight);
}
```

this will make you the _screen will start at 40 and it will hang out at the bottom 40 too.

if you want to make a centered view make it like this:

```
    _screen.frame = CGRectMake(20, 40, screenWidth-40, screenHeight-80);
```

and don't forget to add the screen to the superview like:

```
[self.view addSubview:_screen];
```

I hope it helps.
And one more tip: You can see your _screen frame, if you set `_screen.backgroundcolor = [UIColor orangeColor];` for testing !

Comment: I tried your code :     CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    _screen.frame = CGRectMake(20, 40, 320, screenHeight);
 but the result still the same... the UITextView still not having dynamic height.

Comment: can you show me the full code, where you create the superview too ? it must work. I used these codes in every projects and works perfectly.